# Matplotlib Pcolormesh - in what format should I give the data?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to use matplotlib's pcolormesh function to draw a diagram that shows dots in 2d coordinates, and the color of the dots would be defined by a number.

I have three arrays, one of which has the x-coordinates, another one with the y-coordinates, and the third one has the numbers which should represent colors.

```
xdata = [ 695422.  695423.  695424.  695425.  695426.  695426.]
ydata = [  0.  -15.4 -15.3 -15.7 -15.5 -19. ]
colordata = [   0.  121.   74.   42.    8.    0.]
```

Now, apparently pcolormesh wants its data as three 2d arrays.
In some examples I've seen something like this being done:

```
newxdata, newydata = np.meshgrid(xdata,ydata)
```

Okay, but how do I get colordata into a similar format? I tried to it this way:

```
newcolordata, zz = np.meshgrid(colordata, xdata)
```

But I'm not exactly sure if it's right. Now, if I try to draw the diagram:

```
ax.pcolormesh(newxdata, newydata, newcolordata)
```

I get something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWTGz.png).
No errors, so I guess that's good. The picture it returns obviously doesn't look like what I want it to. Can someone point me into right direction with this? Is the data array still in wrong format?

This should be all of the important code:

```
newxdata, newydata = np.meshgrid(xdata,ydata)
    newcolordata, zz = np.meshgrid(colordata, xdata)

    print newxdata
    print newydata
    print newcolordata

    diagram = plt.figure()







    ax = diagram.add_subplot(111)

    xformat = DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y')

    ax.xaxis_date()




    plot1 = ax.pcolormesh(newxdata, newydata, newcolordata)

    ax.set_title("A butterfly diagram of sunspots between dates %s and %s" % (date1, date2))

    ax.autoscale(enable=False)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformat)
    diagram.autofmt_xdate()



    if command == "save":
        diagram.savefig('diagrams//'+name+'.png')
```

Edit: I noticed that the colors do correspond to the number. Now I just have to turn those equally sized bars into dots.

Comment: reading the accepted answer, I think that the question is misleading: if you want histograms, you shouldn't be looking to pcolormesh, meshgrid ... which are related to showing scalars by interpolation over a regular grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want dots, use `scatter`.  `pcolormesh` draws a grid. `scatter` draws markers colored and/or scaled by size.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = [695422.,695423.,695424.,695425.,695426.,695426.]
ydata = [0.,-15.4,-15.3,-15.7,-15.5,-19.]
colordata = [0.,121.,74.,42.,8.,0.],

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, c=colordata, marker='o', s=200)
ax.xaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

*Edit:*
It sounds like you want to bin your data and sum the areas inside each bin.

If so, you can just use `hist2d` to do this.  If you specify the areas of the sunspots as the `weights` to the histogram, the areas inside each bin will be summed.

Here's an example (data from here: http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/greenwch.shtml, specifically, [this file](http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/greenwch/RGO_NOAA1874_2011.zip), formatted [as described here](http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/greenwch/format.txt)). Most of this is reading the data.  Notice that I'm specifying the `vmin` and then using `im.cmap.set_under('none')` to display anything under that value as transparent.

It's entirely possible that I'm completely misunderstanding the data here. The units may be completely incorrect (the "raw" areas given are in million-ths of the sun's surface area, I think).

```
from glob import glob
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def main():
    files = sorted(glob('sunspot_data/*.txt'))
    df = pd.concat([read_file(name) for name in files])

    date = mdates.date2num(df.date)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
    data, xbins, ybins, im = ax.hist2d(date, df.latitude, weights=df.area/1e4, 
                                       bins=(1000, 50), vmin=1e-6)
    ax.xaxis_date()
    im.cmap.set_under('none')
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im)

    ax.set(xlabel='Date', ylabel='Solar Latitude', title='Butterfly Plot')
    cbar.set_label("Percentage of the Sun's surface") 

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

def read_file(filename):
    """This data happens to be in a rather annoying format..."""
    def parse_date(year, month, day, time):
        year, month, day = [int(item) for item in [year, month, day]]
        time = 24 * float(time)
        hour = int(time)
        minute_frac = 60 * (time % 1)
        minute = int(minute_frac)
        second = int(60 * (minute_frac % 1))
        return dt.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

    cols = dict(year=(0, 4), month=(4, 6), day=(6, 8), time=(8, 12), 
                area=(41, 44), latitude=(63, 68), longitude=(57, 62))
    df = pd.read_fwf(filename, colspecs=cols.values(), header=None, 
                     names=cols.keys(), date_parser=parse_date, 
                     parse_dates={'date':['year', 'month', 'day', 'time']})
    return df

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried using scatter, which I found easier to use. However, I have data for over 100 years, and trying to plot all that stuff gives me a MemoryError.

Comment: So I suppose I should use either PColorMesh or PColor for this.The final picture should look something like this, when I plot all the data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sunspot-bfly.gif

Comment: @user3027287 - Ah! Okay, you just need to grid your data. I'll give an example in just a second.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering! I'll take a look at the histogram function, although I think I may be getting somewhere with pcolormesh. I figured that the spot sizes should be in an diagonal array, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @user3027287 - If you're putting the spot sizes in a diagonal array, you're specifying something wrong.  You need to bin your data onto a regular grid. Then you can display it with `pcolormesh`.  There are multiple ways to go about binning your data, but if you want to sum things inside of each bin, then the easiest way is to use `hist2d` (or use `numpy.histogramdd` and display it yourself with `imshow` or `pcolormesh`).  Otherwise, you'll bin it and then display it with `imshow` (or `pcolormesh`, if you want). Good luck, and I hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I finally got a fairly good result using hist2d, simply using the xdata, ydata and colordata arrays. Thanks for the help!